# how to Add response headers to default page in Vue.Js with .net core application

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core, .net-core, vuejs3, vue-component

I am trying to add custom header on default landing page of my vue.js application. but at that time it doesn't hit any api but i need to add some headers by default due to security vulnerabilities , The application is build on .net core

Note:- there is no server or service called involved at the time when it loads first time i.e it's just a simple login page

Comment: the headers would be added by your web server, the one serving index.html.  whatever web server you're using should have some configuration for doing that.

Comment: @yoduh thanks for commenting but I want to add in my base code instead server

Comment: Your "base code" is the .NET Core server code. In your controller or Razor page you need to add the necessary headers. `i need to add some headers by default due to security vulnerabilities` what headers? You may be able to set them at program startup. CORS for example is configured in the application configuration step